# Help accessing a fan page with Facebook SDK for iOS

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios

I'm working on an app that uses the Facebook iOS SDK and I need some help. I want to post on a fan page and not on the user's wall.

When we do

```
[facebook dialog:@"feed" andDelegate:self];
```

the user posts on his own wall. So I tried this:

```
[facebook dialog:@"/APPLICATION_ID/feed" andDelegate:self];
```

with no result. With the older API it was very simple, the following worked:

```
FBStreamDialog* dialog = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
    dialog.delegate = self;
    dialog.userMessagePrompt = @"Example prompt";

    dialog.targetId = @" APPLICATION_ID ";
```

Unfortunately, this property was removed in the current SDK.

The official documentation explains that we have to change the access_token but don't specify if we must take it for the user or the application, and doesn't explain how to do that.

I tried

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/accounts" andDelegate:self];
```

but the result is an object containing empty data...

Is there something wrong with my code, and is there documentation that I'm unaware of for the iOS SDK?

Comment: Considering SO is the "official" support forum for technical issues with facebook sdk, a whole lot of questions seem to go unanswered...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dialog in the SDK, and specify the "to" parameter.

See 
http://fianbakken.com/wordpress/?p=272

for example on how to post to a fan page a user likes (same as a application page a user likes).